# How to cherry-pick the specific commits of a file?

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

I have 2 branches: `FeatureBranch` and `ReleaseBranch`.

I did cherry-pick a file of commit `c1` from `FeatureBranch` to `ReleaseBranch`.
Later I did some modifications on the same file on `FeatureBranch` & committed with id `c2`.

Again I did enhance the same file on `FeatureBranch` and committed with id `c3`.

Now I do not want `c2` onto `ReleaseBranch`, I only need `c3`. I tried to cherry-pick directly with the `c3` id but Git returned an error:

> could not apply c3...

I know Index in Git is incremental, as I do not want the `c2` changes and I need only `c3`. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: What was the complete error message of `"could not apply c3..."` ?

Comment: error: could not apply c3... on ReleaseBranch  hint:after resolving the conflicts mark the corrected paths. hint: with git add git rm. hint: and commit the result with git commit.

Answer (score 2):

First : you are maintaining two different versions of your code, one on `FeatureBranch`, one on `ReleaseBranch`. You are starting to see the negative effects of having two "live" versions of the code.
I don't know what your constrains are, but "integrating Feature into Release, or ditching Feature" should become a priority milestone in your immediate plans.

---

You are hitting a conflict on that file. git cannot apply `c3` in a straightforward manner, because `c2` introduced some changes, which turn the patch `c2 -> c3` into something which cannot be applied on `Release`.

You will have to manually edit the conflict to fix it, then commit the result.

If the changes in `c2` are simple to discard, another way is to discard the current cherry-pick, get the complete content of the file, and edit it to remove the changes you don't want to commit on Release :

```
# -- from ReleaseBranch

# cancel the cherry-picking :
git cherry-pick --abort

# get the content of the file stored in c3 (will contain modifs from c1+c2+c3) :
git checkout c3 -- path/to/file

# edit the file to remove unwanted code ...

# add and commit
git add path/to/file
git commit
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs LeGEC

Answer (score 1):

What abou reverting c2 on Feature branch (or make separate branch from Feature branch and do revert there) making c4 and cherry pick that. 
I assume the Release branch can be reset to the state before c1.

```
git checkout -b RevertFeatureC2 FeatureBranch
git revert C2
```

OPTION1 - with clean MasterBranch - no C1 C2 (but maybe it will work even if there is C1 C2 already)

```
git checkout MasterBranch
# then cherry pick or merge from RevertFeatureC2
```

OPTION2 - if its ok to overwrite whole file - no separate changes just in MasterBranch(please double check):

```
git checkout ResetFeatureC2 the_file.xyz
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs otopolsky.

Answer (score 0):

To apply changes from `c3` while excluding changes from `c2`, simply use the `git checkout` command to check out the specific file from `c3` to `ReleaseBranch`. Follow these steps to accomplish this:

1. Ensure that you are on `ReleaseBranch`:

```bash
git checkout ReleaseBranch
```

2. Check out the desired file from `c3`:

```bash
git checkout c3 -- path/to/your/file
```

This command imports the file version from commit `c3` into your `ReleaseBranch`.

3. Commit the change:

```bash
git commit -m "Cherry-picked file from c3"
```

This creates a new commit on `ReleaseBranch` that incorporates changes from `c3` for that particular file while excluding changes from `c2`.

It's important to note that this approach is practical only if changes from `c3` don't depend on changes made in `c2`. In cases where they do, you may need to resolve the dependencies or opt to include `c2 manually`.